# my sql exception : duplicate entry for primary key update query

Tags: java, mysql

This error appears to me when I try to execute this query. 
`credit_card_num` is primary key. 
When I execute the query in mysql comand line it works.

```
try {
    conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url, unam, pass);
    st =conn.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("update customer 
                      set credit_card_num ='"+ccnumtex.getText()
                     +"', first_name ='"+fntex.getText()
                     +"' ,last_name ='"+lntex.getText()
                     +"' ,gender='"+com.getSelectedItem()
                     +"', age ='"+agtex.getText()
                     +"', phone='"+phntex.getText()
                     +"',email ='"+Emltex.getText()+"'  ");            

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"information updated");

} catch(Exception ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: I don't see a WHERE condition, and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection big-time.

Comment: As compass said, no where mean every row is updated with same credit_card_num, and that cause the duplicate primary key violation. And that query would fail on command line too, so you are running different queries

Comment: I'm no java expert but I am pretty well versed in writing applications that talk to databases and I know that building a parameterised SQL query by concatenating strings is a REALLY BAD IDEA! http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

You lost "where" condition and "update" statement try to update all rows in table, but fail on unique constraint, i think.
And, please, do not use string concatenation for query params, it make possible "sql-inject" bug.